# Form used to do batch data entry

Tags: ms-access, forms, subform

I have a form called Transaction Entry. I have a subform called Batches. I want to be able to enter a date in the Transaction Entry form, and then enter multiple items on the subform, but have it always update the date from Transaction Entry form.

Basically it would be like what I have drawn out below, and would update the date automatically from the parent from to the subform's date field for every record.![alt text][1]

Comment: Do you want the user to have the ability to change any individual date in the subform?

Comment: No, and I am not good at code. I have an image of the screenshot if that helps.

Comment: Does your Transaction Entry form have a Record Source/is it populating a table?

Answer (score 3):

There should be no need for any code at all. It is possible to use the Link Child & Link Master Fields properties of the subform control (note: the subform control, not the form contained) for just this purpose. You can refer to the name of a control, not just field names in the link properties:

```
Link Master Fields : SomeID, NameOfDateControl

Link Child Fields : SomeID, NameOfDateField
```

Child fields are populated with the contents of the master fields.

Comment: Any expression can be used for Link Master or Link Child. For instance, the easiest way to link a detail continuous form and a single detail form is to have the link of the detail subform be the PK of the current record of the list subform (e.g., DetailForm.Form!PKFieldName). This is one of the glories of Access subforms, and it seems a lot of people who pop up with issues on SO don't even understand basic master/child form/subform structures that work for master/child related tables (e.g., invoice/invoice detail).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing you can do (if you know the subform will never be used anywhere else) is to add a "BeforeInsert" event and then reference the parent form

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeInsert(Cancel As Integer)
    Me.myDate = Forms!parentformname.commonDate
End Sub
```

You could also reference the parent without mentioning the form's name

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeInsert(Cancel As Integer)
    Me.myDate = Me.Parent.commonDate
End Sub
```